# Java - jar: No protocol specified InvocationTargetException

Tags: java

I installed SQLWorkbench.

I moved to `cd /opt/SQLWorkbench` and used `java -jar sqlworkbench.jar`to run the app. The location is correct as the files are there. I'm following this guide: http://www.sql-workbench.net/manual/install.html

However, I get the following error:

```
No protocol specified
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at workbench.WbStarter.main(WbStarter.java:163)
Caused by: java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.access$200(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:65)
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:115)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.<clinit>(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:74)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.createGE(GraphicsEnvironment.java:103)
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:82)
    at sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.<clinit>(XToolkit.java:126)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:860)
    at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:855)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:854)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.getEventQueue(Toolkit.java:1734)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(EventQueue.java:1266)
    at workbench.WbManager.startApplication(WbManager.java:955)
    at workbench.WbManager.main(WbManager.java:1232)
    ... 5 more
```

My `java -version` points to:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_151"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-8u151-b12-0ubuntu0.16.04.2-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```

I'm very new to Linux, and I cannot figure out what is going on.

Comment: Duplicate question on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165761/java-cant-connect-to-x11-window-server-using-localhost10-0-as-the-value-of-t

Comment: I had to do unset DISPLAY. But that does not execute the jar either. It simply does not show the java exception. The problem remains.